# Unable to run cucumber features directly through intellij run configuration

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver

I am getting this stack trace when running a very basic feature which just opens a browser, navigates to google.com and search some string.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
    org/springframework/transaction/TransactionStatus
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2902)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1615)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.MethodScanner.scan(MethodScanner.java:40)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaBackend.loadGlue(JavaBackend.java:86)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:92)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:70)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:66)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:35)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
    org.springframework.transaction.TransactionStatus
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 11 more
```

Can someone tell me what is missing here?

Comment: It is impossible to know what your problem is until you provide some information like your setup, your code, versions, etc..

Comment: https://foreach.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/CWB/pages/1015885/6c+How-to+Q+A

Both IntelliJ 13 and 14 have problems with correctly prefilling the glue property of a run configuration when you are executing a scenario from the UI. You can always modify a run configuration after it has been generated, however the easiest solution is to add the correct glue (usually com.foreach.cuke) to the default run configuration for Cucumber Java.

Comment: I have a maven project with many spring related dependencies. when I run the tests using vm options it works fine but when I right click and try to run an individual feature I get this issue. I hope I'm able to explain the issue here.

Answer (score 11):

For Intellij 2018.1 and i guess for early versions, the Run configuration by default gets the **Glue** 'cucumber.api.spring' , you should switch it for 'com.foreach.cuke'
Go to '**Edit Configurations**' -  '**Cucumber**' - **Glue:** com.foreach.cuke ...

Comment: This can be set in the defaults:

'Edit Configurations...' > 'Templates' > 'Cucumber java' and set the correct Glue for your project.

Answer (score 6):

The below dependency is missing. Default glue `cucumber.api.spring` is not able to find class transaction so it throws an error. Add dependency to your `pom.xml` and it will solve your issue

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should switch The Run configuration to `'com.foreach.cuke'` instead of 'cucumber.api.spring'..

Go to `'Edit Configurations'` - `'Cucumber'` - `Glue: com.foreach.cuke` ...

Answer (score 0):

As far as **`NoClassDefFoundError`** is concerned, it arises due to mismatch between the following components :

1. **`JDK`** version - **`Solution`** - Keep the `JDK` version updated to the recent releases.
2. **`JUnit`** version - **`Solution`** - Keep the `JUnit` version in sync with `cucumber` version.
3. **`Selenium`** version - **`Solution`** - Update the **`Selenium`** version to the recent release versions.
4. **`WebDriver Binary`** version - **`Solution`** - Update the **`WebDriver`** version to the recent release versions.
5. **`Web Browser Binary`** version - **`Solution`** - Update the **`Web Browser`** version to the recent release versions.